# I am running playwright E2E on cloud agent and the agent uses windows server. My E2E tests are unable to access clipboard and I have to access it

Tags: node.js, windows, clipboard, playwright

I am running E2E tests using playwright. The tests run in a pipeline where we set different configurations. The agents all use windows server 2019. My E2E tests can't access clipboard and I have to access it. The method previously implemented in E2E was to use navigator.clipboard.readText() but this method suddenly stopped working 3 weeks ago. My tests are running on my PC completely fine and I have reviewed previous PR and found no bugs related to this issue were pushed. I am very new so I don't understand the major complications but when I used node-clipboardy I received an error of access not granted. When I use navigator.clipboard.readText() E2E trace says that this is not a function. I have checked the permission I have given from config file and those are proper. permissions: ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write'].

I tried simulating Control+V and different clipboard liabraries like node-clipboardy. None of these method are working. Currently I am out of ideas. I feel like its related to windows server.